# Horizontal website on mobile - what viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrolling website using Bootstrap. It looks good on desktops, but I have big problems on mobile. Code simplified:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section id="one">
      stuff here
    </section>
    <section id="two">
       stuff here
    </section>
    <section id="three">
       stuff here
    </section>
    <section id="four">
       stuff here 
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {width:400vw;height:100vh;}
section {100vw;float:left;height:100vh}
```

Now, if I do it like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

On iPhone 5 (and possibly other phones) all the sections show on one page, each 25% of the page, the Bootstrap fixed navbar also takes only 25% of the screen (but collapsed - it has the mobile look).

On the other hand with this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25,maximum-scale=0.25">
```

Every section fits the screen nicely, the page scrolls horizontally like it should, but:

- everything is small - fonts, pictures etc.
- Bootstrap col-sm, col-xs layout doesn't kick in, it looks like desktop layout viewed from far
- Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse - looks like desktop navbar

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use % and viewport device width

Comment: @Jonasw thank you, brilliant! I only have a problem with the navbar now on mobile, but I think I can figure it out.

Comment: no worries :) as im still new to SO and need to earn reputation please mark my answer as solution

Comment: I would have marked it as a solution, but you posted it as a comment so there's no option to mark a comment as a solution. If you repost it as an answer, I sure will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vw isnt really reliable using different browsers use % instead. Its normal to use width=device-width and css font-size to "zoom"